# Simple scan not working after upgrading to 12.10 (Xubuntu)

Tags: scanner, scanning

Since upgrading to 12.10 (Xubuntu), Simple Scan is not working anymore.

I got scanning working with Xsane, but only if Simple Scan has not run before. Otherwise I have to restart the printer/scanner (HP OfficeJet J5783).

In kernel.log I see:

```
kernel: [ 1214.120964] usb 2-1.4: >usbfs: process 4412 (simple-scan) did not claim interface 2 before use
```

and in syslog

```
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 172: unable to read Dot4ReverseCmd header: No data available
simple-scan: io/hpmud/musb.c 1933: invalid Dot4Credit from peripheral
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 172: unable to read Dot4ReverseCmd header: No data available
simple-scan: io/hpmud/musb.c 1933: invalid Dot4Credit from peripheral
simple-scan: sane_hpaio_cancel: already cancelled!
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 172: unable to read Dot4ReverseCmd header: No data available
simple-scan: io/hpmud/musb.c 1933: invalid Dot4Credit from peripheral
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 231: unable to read Dot4ReverseReply header: No data available bytesRead=0
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 319: invalid DOT4InitReply retrying command...
simple-scan: io/hpmud/dot4.c 172: unable to read Dot4ReverseCmd header: No data available
simple-scan: io/hpmud/musb.c 1933: invalid Dot4Credit from peripheral
simple-scan: io/hpmud/hpmud.c 342: device_cleanup: device uri=hp:/usb/Officejet_J5700_series?serial=CN81LCV0V604TC
simple-scan: io/hpmud/hpmud.c 354: device_cleanup: close device dd=1...
simple-scan: io/hpmud/hpmud.c 356: device_cleanup: done closing device dd=1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Open the HPlib toolbox and remove the printer and then reinstall it via the toolbox.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try, but the scanning still doesn't work :-(